# Need guidance with loops and multiples

Tags: java

This is my code so far. It prints the numbers 0 through 10. But I can’t figure out how to multiply each number by 2 and 10.

```
while(numberCounter <= 9){
    System.out.println("Number: " + numberCounter);
    numberCounter++;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: Can you also post more of the code?  The current code should only print numberCounter through 9

Comment: Looking for the `*` operator? If yes: http://www.learnjavaonline.org/

Comment: Expected output is each number multiplied by two and ten. I tried numberCounter  *= 2; but that only gave me even numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you are doing is probably better suited for a `for` loop. Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Number: " + i); // This prints 0-9
}
```

Or for each number times 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Number: " + (i*2)); // This prints 0-9 times 2
}
```

Or for each number times 10:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Number: " + (i*10)); // Prints 0-9 times 10
}
```

Lastly, each number times 10 times 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Number: " + (i*10*2)); // Prints 0-9 times 10 times 2
}
```

You should take a class on Java or read a thorough tutorial or book, because these are very basic Java topics. Try this one: http://www.learnjavaonline.org/

Comment: While this answer is correct, let me add a word of caution. When appending numeric expressions to strings, get in the habit of parenthesizing the expressions. For instance `System.out.println("Number: " + 3+4);` prints "Number: 34". `System.out.println("Number: " + (3 + 4));` prints what you expect.